Games getting stuck inputs after tabbing back in
This is an issue regarding this keyboard
I often play a game on one monitor and watch something else on the second. Whenever I alt-tab out of the game, type something, and tab back in, the game thinks certain keys are being held down when they aren't, causing me to run certain directions, spin the camera, etc. It's essentially creating stuck 'ghost' inputs. I can turn the keyboard off entirely and it's still stuck. When I hit the key for the input in question once, it stops, but this happens every time I tab out and tab back in. I know it's not the game's issue because this has happened over multiple games I've played.
Here are things I've already tried:

updating the firmware
disabling Steam input
turning off and on all connected devices

Restarting the computer fixes it but obviously I don't want to do that every time. It's a very specific issue and I have no clue if it's the keyboard's fault even, but there is some sort of input error somewhere. I tried finding a way to filter out keyboard inputs into certain applications but to no avail, so maybe that can work if anyone knows how to do that. Thanks.

Have you tried a different keyboard?

have you tried pausing the game prior to alt-tabbing? It is my understanding that this is actually an issue for the game to fix, and i know fallout 4 fixed it by pausing the game when you alt-tab back to it, so you must unpause (esc) before resuming play. but it is notable that that game has a discrete pause screen so it may not work as well for all titles. anyway worth a shot.

another thing to look at, is the game running in borderless windowed mode, or full screen mode? for multi-monitor support, borderless windowed mode (at full screen resolution) is generally required to address issues related to the game losing and regaining focus.
